# Webservices developed in AmfPHP -- consume in IOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, amfphp

I have a bunch of webservices developed using `AmfPHP` which are being consumed by a flash application. Can a iOS or Android application use the same webservices ?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS you can use [cocoa-amf](https://github.com/nesium/cocoa-amf).

For android, [aftek](http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-android-amf-library.shtml) has released an AMF library. The catch is that the trial version allows only a limited number of calls.

Comment: hi F21, i am trying to integrate AMFClient in ios but not able to find proper library for it.. i called web-service using simple call it works fine with this framework. The AMFclient library given in Cocoa-amf contains lots bugs and some files are missing. so if you find any thing about AMFClient library please help me my mail ID is -: ishbimal@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Adobe site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dataservicesjee/4.6/Developing/WS4976f0ec3ef48246-1c24bbe312dc391a64f-8000.html#WS4976f0ec3ef48246-44c8a7a912dc3bcf6f2-8000) you need to use flex-messaging-client-android.jar.  I've tested it and it seems to work fine.